# Cytoscape-cxtmenu.js : Displaying Menu commands based on condition

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape, cytoscape-web

I have an app using cytoscape version 3.15.2 and cxtmenu library version 3.1.1. I have a case where I want to add conditions on some edges based on a condition. I have a command called 'info', which I am applying on the menu's on all edges in the graph:

```
let edges = {
            menuRadius: 100, 
            selector: 'edge', 
            commands: [ ...
                { // info command
                    .........              
                }
            ]
        }
```

I have another command called "expand", which I want to apply on edges which have a value true for the expand attribute on the edge. So for the edges that satisfy this condition, I want to have both the info and the expand command available. For this, I created another menu variable as follows

```
let expandEdges = {
            menuRadius: 100, 
            selector: 'edge[expand=true]', 
            commands: [ ...
                { // info command
                    .........              
                },
                { // expand command
                    .........              
                }
            ]
        }
```

When I use this implementation where I apply both the menu variables to the graph, I see the following on my graph.

[image]

If you observe, the info and expand commands are overlapped by the info command I applied on all edges. Im not sure how to use selector conditions to apply commands to all edges and some commands based on conditions.

I also wanted to know if I can use something like selector: 'edge[type.contains'expand']' (substring check) as a selector condition.

Also, I've not been able to create a reproducible example as this is part of a very huge app. Sorry for that.

Comment: You can use collections for this probably. Just create one collection containing all "expand" edges and another one containing the other edges. Add the menus just to the correct collection.

Comment: @StephanT. Could you explain a bit more about collections please.

Comment: A collection is just a set of elements, so a collection can, for example, contain all elements ```let elements = cy.elements();```. The function cy.elements() returns a collection containing all nodes and edges present in the graph. If you have some sort of logic to differentiate between edges (you mentioned the expand = true part in your code), then you can create a collection contining all edges with said expand = true property. You can create another collection containing all edges with expand = false. With these two, just add your event listeners to the correct collection.

Comment: I just noticed that ctxmenus doesn't use eventlisteners in the extensions api, so you can't use that. The easy solutiion would be to use selectors for both menus. The first one just has edge as the selector, change that to something more strict like edge[expand=false]